# Scheduled Uploading

Tags: sql, database, bash, oracle, file-upload

how to upload .txt files on daily basis to an oracle database,
what kind of scripting do i need to learn to cover this task.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiastic programmers. Add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using Browser based Oracle Database management, then you can easily create daily scheduling Script Using Browser automation Studio. this is free tools for creating automation tools:https://bablosoft.com/shop/BrowserAutomationStudio#features

Answer (score 0):

That depends on option you choose.

If it is **SQL*Loader**, it requires you to create a control file which will be used to read the .txt file and insert its contents into the database. *Pro* in this option is that SQL*Loader runs on your local computer. As it is an executable, you can schedule it using your operating system scheduling utility, such as MS Windows' Task Scheduler. People usually create a batch (.bat) script which is then used to call the loading utility.

Or, if you choose to keep it within the database, create a **stored procedure** which utilizes `UTL_FILE` built-in package to read the .txt file and insert its value into the table. *Contra* for this option is that you have to have access to the database server as `UTL_FILE` requires access to a directory (both an Oracle object and physical directory on the disk) to perform this operation. As in the previous option, you'd schedule it using `DBMS_JOB` or `DBMS_SCHEDULER` (depending on database version you use and complexity of the scheduling process).

Alternatively, if you create an **external table** (which, basically, points to the .txt file and uses SQL*Loader in the background), you can write a procedure which will read that table and, again, insert rows into the table.